# bignum in emacs/elisp

Tags: elisp, biginteger, bignum

Does emacs have support for big numbers that don't fit in integers? If it does, how do I use them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Emacs Lispers frustrated by Emacs’s
>   lack of bignum handling: `calc.el`
>   provides very good bignum
>   capabilities.—*EmacsWiki*

`calc.el` is part of the GNU Emacs distribution. See its source code for available functions. You can immediately start playing with it by typing `M-x quick-calc`. You may also want to check [bigint.el package](http://www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/skyserver/bigint.el), that is a non-standard, lightweight implementation for handling bignums.

Comment: Looks like this'll do the job... calc looks a bit daunting at first look, but I'll figure it out eventually. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs 27.1 supports bignums natively (see [the NEWS file of Emacs](https://fossies.org/linux/emacs/etc/NEWS)):

> ** Emacs Lisp integers can now be of arbitrary size.
> Emacs uses the GNU Multiple Precision (GMP) library to support
> integers whose size is too large to support natively.  The integers
> supported natively are known as "fixnums", while the larger ones are
> "bignums".  The new predicates 'bignump' and 'fixnump' can be used to
> distinguish between these two types of integers.
>
> All the arithmetic, comparison, and logical (a.k.a. "bitwise")
> operations where bignums make sense now support both fixnums and
> bignums.  However, note that unlike fixnums, bignums will not compare
> equal with 'eq', you must use 'eql' instead.  (Numerical comparison
> with '=' works on both, of course.)
>
> Since large bignums consume a lot of memory, Emacs limits the size of
> the largest bignum a Lisp program is allowed to create.  The
> nonnegative value of the new variable 'integer-width' specifies the
> maximum number of bits allowed in a bignum.  Emacs signals an integer
> overflow error if this limit is exceeded.
>
> Several primitive functions formerly returned floats or lists of
> integers to represent integers that did not fit into fixnums.  These
> functions now simply return integers instead.  Affected functions
> include functions like 'encode-char' that compute code-points, functions
> like 'file-attributes' that compute file sizes and other attributes,
> functions like 'process-id' that compute process IDs, and functions like
> 'user-uid' and 'group-gid' that compute user and group IDs.

Bignums are automatically chosen when arithmetic calculations with fixnums overflow the fixnum-range. The expression `(bignump most-positive-fixnum)` returns `nil` while `(bignump (+ most-positive-fixnum 1))` returns `t`.